# I'm Getting this error while replacing the colors.xml file

Tags: android-studio

Android resource compilation failed
Output:  ------\app\src\main\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher_round.xml:1: error: syntax error.

Command: -------\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\e8f3f35941cfd68ed95c8ffe5df71903\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
        -o \
       -----
project\SocialIntegration\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
       ----\SocialIntegration\app\src\main\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher_round.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0

Comment: What did you replace you colors.xml with? Maybe you could share the before and after versions colors.xml. It seems there is a syntax error.

Comment: Please put your code in suggested format during typing the question. And elaborate some details.

Comment: Solved that was a version error.. Just update ide